# Can I straighten up every zigzag line?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

[image]

Is it possible in Adobe Illustrator to straighten up this track removing the zigzag?

I want to create a line, or a curve, depending on the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use **Object → Path → Simplify**.

There you can control how straight etc. you want it.

If you want only a straight line, select **Straight Lines**

[image: Simplify Modal]

<sup>▲ Red is before, Blue is result.</sup>

Comment: Good answer, but for the sake of completeness might be good to see [an example showing a curved zigzag](https://imgur.com/a/uKuua4h) simplified.

Comment: @BillyKerr so interesting! My results look **nothing** like yours when I tried making curved.

Comment: Interesting. I experimented a little and found that I get different results when I try it with pixel snapping on versus off, and different results depending on the size of the initial path. A smaller path results in more smoothing.